# what exactly if ((i = fis.read()) != -1) means in this program?

Tags: java

```
package IO;
import java.io.*;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File f1 = new File("C:\\Users\\rs\\New folder\\myname.txt");
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f1);
        int i = fis.read();     
        System.out.print((char)i);
        while((i = fis.read())!= -1) {
            System.out.print((char) i );
        }
        
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    

 }

}
```

I am a new java programmer and i have a trouble in this code. This code reads bytes from my file (f1) and I can cast this bytes to char and print them, but something is here that I do not understand and its the condition in my while loop. What it exactly means? I mean what exactly `if ((i = fis.read()) != -1)` means??? And the second question is why we put
`i = fis.read()` in a paranthesis???
My file has a text (1 line) in it.

Comment: probably, `for (int i = fis.read(), i >= 0, i = fis.read()) {
            System.out.print((char) i ); }` is more readable

Comment: Note that 1) input streams are for reading bytes, not chars: use an `InputStreamReader` if you want to read chars; 2) the read on the variable declaration and immediately following print shouldn't be there: if the file is empty, the read will yield -1.

Comment: "why we put i = fis.read() in a parenthesis" because of [operators precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/). Assignment operator `=` has lower precedence than comparison operator `!=` or `==` so if we have code like `a = b == c` it would be interpreted as if it was written like `a = (b == c)` but in case of your example you first want to assign value from `fis.read()` to `i` and then compare it against `-1`.

Comment: Also your code doesn't contain `if ((i = fis.read()) != -1)` but `while ((i = fis.read()) != -1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#read()) 's `read()` method follows this logic:

> *Reads a byte of data from this input stream.
> This method blocks if no input is yet available.*

The method will **return**:

> *The next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached.*

So `-1` is its flag for the `EOF` check. With this in mind, this code snippet

```
while((i = fis.read())!= -1) 
      System.out.print((char) i);
```

Is telling that:

**1**. Assign `fis.read()` to the var `i`

**2a**. If `i != -1`, print the `ASCII char` representing the integer just read from the inputstream, and *continue the loop*.

**2b**. If `i == -1`, *end the loop* / stop reading, because it reached the end of file.

Answer (score 4):

**First Question**

That means you would continue reading from the stream until you reached the end. When `fis.read()` returns `-1`, that means that you reached the end of the stream and there is no more data to read.

**Second Question**

```
i = fis.read() != -1
```

You might get the impression that the compiler does not know the proper order of execution and there are two scenarios:

- We check `fis.read() != -1` (`boolean` result) then assign it to `i`
- We get `fis.read()` and assign it to `i` then check `i != -1`

But java has well-defined rules, there is only one because of operator precedence.

See the table at:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Assignment has a lower precedence than `!=`, so definitely the first scenario will happen.
But that is not what we want. (We don't want `i` to be the boolean result of `fis.read() != -1`)

Also see:
[https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/#:~:text=Java%20has%20well-defined%20rules,be%20overridden%20by%20explicit%20parentheses](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/#:%7E:text=Java%20has%20well-defined%20rules,be%20overridden%20by%20explicit%20parentheses).

**"Precedence rules can be overridden by explicit parentheses"**

So we explicitly put the parentheses to make sure the statement inside it (`i = fis.read()`) is executed first and the second scenario happens.

Answer (score 2):

It means

> "read until the find the end of file char".

And for the second question:

```
while((i = fis.read())!= -1) {
    System.out.print((char) i );
}
```

The `(i = fis.read())` defines that "i variable" for the print below while check if it's different from `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of `(i = fis.read())!= -1` as doing two separate things.

First `i = fis.read()` is executed. That is, you read a byte from the input stream. If there is nothing to read then i is set to -1.

Second this comparison happens: `i != -1` If that is true the loop continues. If that is false the loop ends.